# When not to use LM358

Tags: operational-amplifier

I often find myself in need of op amps which I know very little about, I only have LM358, LM324 (same thing) and LM393 (comparator I know),

Most of circuits online do not use LM358 but I think it could work for testing, I cannot buy each one to test my theories or circuits,

My current use case is to add some gain to rx (receiving coil) of a metal detector that I might try to make in future but first I need to know if I can make any sense of signal received from the coil before I waste any further time and precious copper, if it works I can replace the temporary LM358 with a suitable one, will be working within 10khz range dc square or might do ac

Other than bandwidth limitations and noise, what other factors should I consider before wasting my time with LM358?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  The LM358 is a commonly used and inexpensive op-amp device.  What are your concerns about it?

Comment: For example in a circuit that I found,  OP07 was used as main op-amp, LM358 was there but for other reasons, can I use LM358 there? If designer went for OP07 there must be a reason? @jwh20

Comment: We might be able to figure that out - but only if you show us a schematic.

Comment: Thats the question, I want to figure that out myself just like you would so I don't have to post schematics everytime and ask if LM358 would work there instead @Jonathan

Comment: which sort of metal detector do you want to build?

Comment: Vlf with double d coil at 5~6 khz @Jasen

Comment: The question as asked is much too broad or really simple, whichever way you look at it. The simple answer is: evaluate a particular circuit's op-amp requirement then compare these to the LM358N datasheet. So standard design principles. VTC, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, when the 324/358 isn't good enough. For instance you might want Rail To Rail input and/or output. You might want lower noise. You might want a higher gain bandwidth product. You might want to avoid the LM324's quirky output stage that has some crossover distortion. You might want to use higher voltage rails- or be in a very low voltage scenario.

The 324/58 are pretty good for a lot of applications but not for some. For instance, for a good quality low noise audio circuit the NE5532 is a much better choice, because it has low noise and negligible output distortion.

Comment: *"or be in a very low voltage scenario"*  I might be dealing with microvolts

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I meant low voltage power rails, not inputs.

Comment: Hi, I am looking all OP AMP questions and trying to get something. I am wondering if I use filter for 125 kHz (I want to make 125 kHz RFID reader) , should I choose OP-AMP which have 125 kHz gain ? or If I choose higher gain, will be better?

Comment: @Tryingtogetsome you should ask this as a question really. But higher is better. Most op amps have much better gain bandwidth product that 125kHz anyway, but remember if you did find one with a GBP of .125MHz, it can only just pass a sinewave at that frequency with no gain.